# How to change the value of a specific integer with math operation? Using map-replace.js

Tags: json

Please see the example below to help explain the issue I'm facing. I have tons of this to edit. I was trying to use map-replace.js to do it but I stuck.

Firstly, I did a regrex search `"base-sell-price": "(.*)"`.
Secondly, I use the map-replace.js
Thirdly, (v, i) => `${v*2}`

```
{
          "tradeable-code": "Weapon_AK47",
          "base-purchase-price": "-1",
          "base-sell-price": "10000",
          "delta-price": "1",
          "can-be-purchased": "default",
          "required-famepoints": "-1"
        },
        {
          "tradeable-code": "Weapon_AK47_Engraved",
          "base-purchase-price": "-1",
          "base-sell-price": "25000",
          "delta-price": "1",
          "can-be-purchased": "default",
          "required-famepoints": "-1"
        },
        {
          "tradeable-code": "Weapon_AKM",
          "base-purchase-price": "-1",
          "base-sell-price": "8000",
          "delta-price": "1",
          "can-be-purchased": "default",
          "required-famepoints": "-1"
        },
```

I want all the base-sell-price multiplied by 2.

```
{
          "tradeable-code": "Weapon_AK47",
          "base-purchase-price": "-1",
          "base-sell-price": "20000",
          "delta-price": "1",
          "can-be-purchased": "default",
          "required-famepoints": "-1"
        },
        {
          "tradeable-code": "Weapon_AK47_Engraved",
          "base-purchase-price": "-1",
          "base-sell-price": "50000",
          "delta-price": "1",
          "can-be-purchased": "default",
          "required-famepoints": "-1"
        },
        {
          "tradeable-code": "Weapon_AKM",
          "base-purchase-price": "-1",
          "base-sell-price": "1600",
          "delta-price": "1",
          "can-be-purchased": "default",
          "required-famepoints": "-1"
        },
```